# Kernel module remove not permitted for some sudo users

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, kernel-modules

I use a `sudoers` file, which (besides other items) contains following lines:

```
homebridge    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/modprobe -r bcm2835-v4l2, /sbin/modprobe bcm2835-v4l2, /sbin/reboot
%sudo         ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/modprobe -r bcm2835-v4l2, /sbin/modprobe bcm2835-v4l2, /sbin/reboot
```

When I execute the following command `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/modprobe -r bcm2835-v4l2` with my *regular user*, this works fine without requiring to enter password.

When I run `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/modprobe -r bcm2835-v4l2` using the *homebridge* user mentioned in the sudoers as well, the command fails with output: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted` (, but I am also not asked to enter password)

I am able to execute the `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot` command successfully with the *homebridge* user as well not requiring to enter password.

1. Can you tell what could cause the fact that for both users the rule seem to be applied, as I'm not asked for a password but one of the the two user is not able to run it?
2. And how to fix this, so I'm able to run the command using the `homebridge` user?

**Update 1:**
Unfortunately, `dmesg` contains no additional entries when trying unsuccessful using *homebridge* user, but follwoing line when using regular user: `bcm2835-v4l2-0: unregistering video0`

I switched to `bcm2835_v4l2` instead of `bcm2835-v4l2`, but this does not seem to have an effect on the issue.
Executing `lsmod | grep bcm2835-v4l2` provided no results, while `lsmod | grep bcm2835_v4l2` provided following:

```
bcm2835_v4l2           40960  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     28672  3 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  4 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
videobuf2_common       61440  5 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              249856  6 bcm2835_isp,bcm2835_codec,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
```

No entries in `syslog` when unsuccessful trying with *homebridge* user.

**Update 2:**
There is no `/var/log/secure` available, but  `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
homepi sudo: homebridge : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/homebridge ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/modprobe -r bcm2835_v4l2
homepi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
homepi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

**Update 3:**
If I unload the module using *regular user*, and try to load using *homebridge* user, I also cannot load module:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/modprobe bcm2835_v4l2 && echo 1
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted`.
```

If the module is already loaded when trying with *homebridge* user, no error:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/modprobe bcm2835_v4l2 && echo 1
1
```

**Update 3:**
Using *homebridge* user:

```
capsh --print
Current: = cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw+eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_admin,cap_audit_write
Securebits: xxxxxxxx
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=999(homebridge)
gid=995(homebridge)
groups=20(dialout),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),105(input),112(bluetooth),995(homebridge),997(gpio)
```

Using *regular* user:

```
capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,38,39,40
Securebits: xxxxx
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=4814(regularUserName)
gid=4814(regularUserName)
groups=4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(input),109(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi),4814(regularUserName)
```

Indeed, *homebridge* user is not having `cap_sys_module` assigned. What does this mean and can it be fixed?

**Update 4**

```
lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

Comment: @AndyDalton: if the refcount>0, wouldn't it be something like "device or resource busy" in  stead of Operation not permitted? @Erik: besides `dmesg`, does the sudo-logging (probably `/var/log/secure`) say anything useful?

Comment: As the `homebridge` please run `capsh --print` and update your question with the result.  I'm guessing that user's process doesn't have `cap_sys_module`.

Comment: I'm not sure what in Raspbian would be causing that capability to be dropped.  Maybe someone else will have an idea.

Comment: ...and can somebody explain how I can make the user in question able to get this capability?